# How can you recover a SQL Server database if the ldf file has been deleted

Tags: sql-server, disaster-recovery

We had a drive die and lost the ldf file, but the mdf file is in tact.  Is there a process for re-connecting to the mdf file, considering the ldf lost?  I have searched without much luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://irina2dose.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/sql-20052008-database-recovery-procedure-%E2%80%93-log-file-deleted-part-3/). It is explained how to recover the database.

Comment: I'm marking this correct because we had Microsoft Support on the box, and this was basically what they did.  Plus they executed the rebuild log command here: http://sql-developer2dba.blogspot.com/2010/04/rebuild-log-in-sql-2005-sql-server.html

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can try detaching the database and attaching it using the [sp_attach_single_file_db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174385%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx) system stored procedure.  This will generate a new transaction log file for you.  If this procedure fails, you will need to restore from your backup.

Comment: if there was an active transaction than SQL will not be able to create a new log file knowing that a transaction was not committed and the attach will fail. It will be much harder after a detach to attach a corrupted database. The easy way is to use emergency mode. Much safer.

Answer (score 1):

> but the mdf file is in tact

Yes, but not consistent. Data files are not kept consistent between checkpoints - this is why you need an LDF file.

I suggest a backup. While you MAY be lucky with the sp_attach_single_file_db it is 99.9% a data loss involved.